# C++ - Code works on my machine but not on my school server ( cin.getline( ) )

Tags: c++, cin

this piece of code worked fine on my machine, but it doesn't on my school server. 
The program is a simple text editor and that little part just prints out error when there was no line number input.

This is just a segment of my code. On my machine, when no line number is inputted, it goes to the if statement. On the server however, it doesn't Instead all blank spaces become '0'.

```
char c[6];
int line = 0;
cin.getline( c, 6 );

.
.
.

else if( c[0] == 'I' ){
    line = atoi( &c[2] );

        if( c[2] == '\0' ){
            cout << "Missing line number for insert" << endl;
        }
}
```

Any idea? Or anybody know a better way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is the complete code; how is `else if(...)` supposed to compile?

Comment: How does it "not work" on the other machine? What is the behavior you're expecting? What's the behavior you're getting instead?

Comment: “doesn’t work” is not a sufficient error description. Furthermore, this code doesn’t compile (anywhere!) and contains at least one rather glaring error. Please post the *real*, complete, but minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: it's just a segment of my code, this is the only part it doesn't work. On my machine when no line number is inputted, it goes to the if statement, however, when I run it on the server, it doesn't. Instead c[2] or any other blank spaces become '0'

Comment: @David This is still insufficient, for the reasons I have pointed out in my comment.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph It actually is, thanks though. Someone already answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you build in debug mode at home, in which case your 'c' buffer gets initialized with zeros. And at school, you build with 'release' mode, in which case your c buffer is not initialized, but will have indeterminate values.

You should initialized your 'c' buffer with zeros with a line like

```
char c[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Comment: /* or you can use: */
char c[6] = {0};